# How to remove "Welcome to phpMyAdmin" text from phpmyadmin login

Tags: phpmyadmin

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ZOHh.png)

How to remove "Welcome to phpMyAdmin" text from phpmyadmin login

Comment: You can edit the corresponding php file

Comment: I know but when i try it localhost then it is happening but in my production server is not happening and not showing the .twig file centos server

Comment: Don't let phpMyAdmin on production server, use rather a non-web tool like MySQL Workbench